# 'disable' attribute of option HTML element is not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

i'm facing a problem in disabling an 'Option' HTML element within a 'Select' HTML element group in IE8.
Below is my Code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="vauxhall">Vauxhall</option>
    <option disabled="true"  value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  </body>
  </html>
```

if i try to run the above code in IE8, i see it as disabled inside dropdown list. However, if i start to type or key in 'Ope..' it appears for selection in the dropdown textbox.

In Firefox, Chrome it works fine, i.e. typing doesn't allow it for selection in dropdowns textbox.

when i searched on net, i found one workaround which suggests to replace "Option" with "Optgroup" element, but it doesn't seems to be a good solution since i need to :
              1. apply CSS to make it look like its disabled.
              2. and do scpriting to replace Option with Optgroup and vice-versa while enabling/disabling dropdown elemnts

this is the Link which gives this workaround

http://harrybailey.com/2008/11/disabling-select-options-in-internet-explorer/

Can anyone please tell me if there is a correct way to disable option element in IE8 or am i missing the right attribute?

--- Thanks

Abhinav Ganguly

Comment: So you are saying you can select it by keyboard? What happens if you try to get the value of the select element? Is it returning the value of the disabled option?

Comment: Yes! i can select it using Keyboard (but only in IE8) if i try to see the value in alert statement i see it as 'Null'.          Thing im trying to achieve is if i select particular option from dropdown once, i shouldn't be allowed to select and add it once again.